# How do you embed a GAS user's google calender on a standalone web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Developing a web app which should enable users to organize the events on their calender without navigating from the app. How do you embed a GAS user's google calender on a standalone web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed the users calendar UI (user interface) directly in your app. Currently there is no 'calendar-widget' that emulates the google-calendar UI. There is however a simple calendar widget called 'DatePicker' but on assumption i don't think that's what you mean.

You can however interact with the user's calendar at a data-level with the calendar service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_calendar.
Keep in mind that the security level in this case is very important. If you publish your web-app to execute as the current user, it can interact freely with that user's calendar.
If it's set to execute as you (the maker of the script) it can't access that user's calendar. It can only access that calendar if it's security level has been adjusted to be shared and editable by and with you (by the owner of that calendar).

In all, the read/write/access rules are exactly the same as if you use the services as 'normal' thru google's own webservices. Keep that in mind when developing your app and you avoid a lot of headaches ;-)

Comment: Thanks Tim, How useful do you think the inserting calendar widget on google sites can be?

Comment: The DatePicker widget is just that. It's a datepicker. It enables the user to define dates. It can be extremely usefull but all in context to your app and what you do with the input. Maybe i'm having trouble understanding what you're asking? If you don't mean the widget but the google calendar service. Then no.

Why? Almost all current modern browsers have tabbed views so the user can have multiple pages active without having to leave one site to navigate to another. It's no problem to have one tab with the google calendar service open and another tab with your web-app and switch between them.